Git fetch a second branch after cloning with --single-branch
I cloned a repository by using --single-branch:
git clone -b frontend --single-branch https://repo/branch-test.git

Now I want to fetch 1 more branch called backend from the remote in the same local folder.
git checkout, git pull, git fetch seem to not work.
The only workaround I found is to:
git fetch origin backend:refs/remotes/origin/backend
git checkout FETCH_HEAD

But this puts me in a detached HEAD state, which is not desirable.

I guess you ran git fetch origin backend and then git checkout backend failed.
You have several options.
Create the local backend from FETCH_HEAD.
git fetch origin backend
git checkout -b backend FETCH_HEAD

Or, create the local backend from origin/backend.
git fetch origin backend:refs/remotes/origin/backend
git checkout -b backend origin/backend

Or, create the local backend as usual.
# Add a config option for once
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git fetch origin backend
git checkout backend

remote.origin.fetch would be automatically created without --single-branch. Lacking it makes git checkout backend not work as expected.
For the 2nd case, there is a similar solution.
git fetch origin backend:refs/remotes/origin/backend
git checkout backend # FAIL
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git checkout backend # SUCCEED


Both method 1 and 2 do not set up tracking between the local backend branch and the remote origin/backend branch.

Method 3 with git config ... seems to work, thanks

Modify remote origin and then apply unshallow
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git fetch --unshallow  


You can perform the following commands to fetch another branch from the remote repository without entering a detached HEAD state: 
Fetch the branch: 
      git fetch origin backend

Create a local tracking branch: 
      git checkout -b backend origin/backend

Switch to the new branch: 
      git checkout backend


This fails fatal: 'origin/backend' is not a commit and a branch 'backend' cannot be created from it.
